# Solve this differential equation when $y(0)=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y''-xy=0$, $y(0)=\alpha$, $y'(0)=\beta$. Also, $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ is a solution to y.

Is this differential equation first order linear? And if $\alpha=1$, $\beta=0$, then does $a_0=1, a_1=0$? (recall that $a_n$ is the series)

For the first question, my answer is yes. Also if $\alpha=0, \beta=0$, then $y(0)=1, y'(0)=0$. I'm not really sure how $\alpha, \beta$ are related to the equation, but my intuition tells me that this is true. Intuitions are not really that reliable so I wanted to verify if this is true or not.

Comment: This is not a first-order equation as there's a second-order derivative. It is linear though.

Comment: @StephenDonovan thank you for the correction. What about my second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a first-order equation as we have a $y''$ in the equation. This is a second-order linear equation with non-constant coefficients.

Let's rewrite the form of our solution as $y = a_0 + a_1x + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ so that $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ are well-defined. Now consider what happens when we plug in $x = 0$ into our sum: all the higher-order terms should cancel and we will get $a_0 = \alpha.$

Now consider taking a derivative on both sides: $y' = a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n\cdot nx^{n-1}.$ Now plugging in $x = 0$ on both sides should give us $y'(0) = a_1 = \beta.$ So, the answer to the second question should be yes.